# How can i get this Javascript code to work in Nextjs TSX Extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

**I have already done the dynamic Import but i am not sure what to do from here.**

Error
TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
TS2339: Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'Element'.
TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.

```
     const fields = (document.querySelectorAll(".login-form input") as unknown as HTMLInputElement).value;

let btn = document.querySelector(".logbtn");

function checked(){ 
     if((fields[0]).value != "" && fields[1].value != "") btn.disabled = true; 
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'